# authenticating quickbooks online ipp api explorer

Tags: oauth, saml, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to test the Quickbooks online api using the credentials Intuit provides in my developer center.  The api sandbox will not authenticate me.  http://apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com/V3QBO#api

**What is missing to connect the api explorer to my Quickbooks online database?**

The error message after clicking "Connect to QuickBooks":

> Oops! An error has occurred. Please close this window and try again.
>
> Error Code: invalid_database  Message: AppId cannot be <= 0, appId=-1

Authentication login frame:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have signed up for the v3 beta program and been accepted you cannot use v3 of the Quickbooks API.

v2 Will work fine for you
http://apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com/V2QBO

You can see a short video here on how to set up and use the API Explorer.
http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/01/new-ipp-developer-tool-api-explorer.html

regards,
Jarred

Comment: Jarred, thanks for the note on v3 and your video which explained everything I needed to do.  My mistake was selecting "Customer Account Data" instead of "Intuit Anywhere" when creating my app.  

For anyone else looking for answers view the video http://youtu.be/8cugeQUbFhM and fast forward to the 2:15 mark.